# Element reference inside Radzen DataGrid Not set (Blazor)

Tags: blazor

I have a Radzen Blazor DataGrid, and I want to have a ElementReference inside one of its columns for each row to be created, so that I show a tooltip for these references, First I created a dictionary that contains element references keyed by record Id:

```
Dictionary<int, ElementReference> spans = new Dictionary<int, ElementReference>();
void ShowTooltip(ElementReference elementReference, string content, TooltipOptions options = null) 
    => tooltipService.Open(elementReference, content, options);
```

and this is the column in the datagrid that I want to have a reference to it:

```
<RadzenGridColumn TItem="Appointment" Property="Text" Title="Text" Sortable="true" SortProperty="Text"
                          Filterable="true" FilterProperty="Text">
            <Template Context="item">                    
                <span @ref=spans[item.Id] @onmouseover=@(() => ShowTooltip(spans[item.Id], item.Text))>                   
                @if (item.IsDone)
                {
                    <del style="font-size: 1.2rem;">@item.Text</del>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span style="font-size: 1.2rem;">@item.Text</span>
                }
                </span>
            </Template>
        </RadzenGridColumn>
```

with this setup only at the first load tooltips show so I added a line of code before Loading the grid data that creates a new dictionary before loading grid data:

```
 async Task LoadData(LoadDataArgs args, GetSchedulesModel model)
{
   ...

    try
    {
        //spans.Clear();
        spans = new Dictionary<int, ElementReference>();
        
        (Model, count) = home.GetSchedules(selectedTypeID, model.Filter, model.FilterDueDate, model.DueStart, model.DueEnd,
            model.FilterDone, model.Done, model.FilterListStatus, model.ListStatus,
            model.FilterArgs, model.ArgsFilter, model.Sort, model.ArgsOrderBy, model.ArgsTop, model.ArgsSkip);          
        StateHasChanged();

        ModelSuccess = true;
    ...
  }
```

But still (with the second load, for example paging) I get the empty dictionary with a not found key. How to correct this?